How to properly set versioning pipeline in Gitlab
I have troubles with setting versioning pipeline in GitLab.
What is my goal:

when it is pushed to main branch (either by commit or MR) the tag with version number is added to commit
also version number is added to file within repository (something like version.py and there is version variable which holds version number)

What I achieved:

first part - I have working pipeline which runs when CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == main. It creates and pushes version tag to remote

What I have troubles with:

I don't know when and how to properly update version number in the file (I know how to do it technically, I can update the version number in file, I don't know how to correctly push it to repository so it is there when next job runs).

Pipeline:
version-job:
  stage: version
  variables:
    VERSION_FILE_PATH: "<path-to-version-file>"
  image: <custom-image>
  script:
    - python3 /version_app/main.py
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH== "main"
  tags:
    - <runner-tag>

Versioning functionality:
def update_version_in_file(file_path, version):
    if not os.path.exists(file_path):
        logger.warning(f"Unable to write version to file. File path '{file_path}' does not exist")
        return

    logger.info(f"Updating version in file to: {version}")
    with open(file_path,"r+", encoding="utf-8") as v:
        tree = ast.parse(v.read())
        updater = VersionUpdater(version)
        tree = updater.visit(tree)
        v.seek(0)
        v.write(astor.to_source(tree))
    
    
    git("add",file_path)
    git("commit","-m",f"File version update {version}")

def main():
    version = func_to_get_version()
    git("config","http.sslCAInfo",CERTIFICATE_PATH)
    git("config","user.email","<...>")
    git("config","user.name","<...>")

    version_file_path = os.environ.get("VERSION_FILE_PATH","./app/version.py")

    update_version_in_file(version_file_path,version)
    tag_repo(version)
    git("push", "origin", version)

    return 0


Can't you use something like setuptools-git-versioning?

the system should generate a version based on the distance to the last git tag. Therefore in the version-job (python), a command like
git describe --tags --always --long

should be executed and it will return the last tag with the commit, like
v0.1.1-2-g2156f2b

which v0.1.1 is the tag and 2156f2b is the short commit sha. Now we compare $CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA (last commit in branch) with the short commit and then if there is a difference, we will update the version file and create a tag. If not, we exit successfully.
